# searching for filenames in folders and subfolders of a directory and get files that match a pattern in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have to search for files(Filenames) that match a pattern in a given directory (folders and subfolders.)

I want the list of names of files that match following conditions (to display to user)

1. file extension should be .txt
2. Character that comes before the last . (period) is not a number.

Ex: If a directory contains following files,

> Example1.11.0.3.2-beta.txt
> Example2.11.0.3.txt
> Example3.11.0.3.3-gamm.txt
> Example1.11.0.4.txt

I want 1st and 3rd fileNames to be displayed to user (because it does not contain a number before last).

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed to the user? Just printed in the console? Do you need it to show the full filepath if it is searching subfolders? or just show filenames only regardless of the folder?

Comment: Yes, i want the file with full path to be displayed to user

Answer (score 2):

The **PowerShell** documentation states that, Whenever possible, [it's good practice to use the `-Filter` parameter (if available)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-compare-two-outputs-from-measure-command) of the *PSProvider* (in this case, the FIleSystem provider) because it is more efficient than either wildcards in the `-Path` parameter or subsequent filtering with the '`include/-exclude` parameters or piping to `Where-Object`.

Becasue **PowerShell**'s [wildcard implememtation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards) adds characater sets/ranges in addition to the more familiar `*` and `?`, I initially thought the OP's desired selection can be contained entirely in the `-Filter` parameter:

```
(gci -Path .\ -Filter *[a-zA-Z].txt -Recurse).FullName
```

But that produced no results, Because the FIleSystem provider doean't recognize the range specification. So while the `-Filtter` parameter can take care of the `*.txt` requirement, `Where-Object` is still needed to exclude BaseNames that end with a digit:

```
(gci -Filter *.txt -Recurse | ? BaseName -match '\D$').FullName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get-ChildItem` recursively with a match statement.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem "d:\temp" -recurse | where {$_.name -match "[a-zA-Z].txt"} | select name
```

If your folder structure was:

```
\Temp\alpha.txt
\Temp\alpha44.txt
\Temp\Folder1\beta.txt
\Temp\Folder1\beta22.txt
\Temp\Folder2\gamma.txt
\Temp\Folder2\77gamma.txt
```

This query would return:

```
alpha.txt
beta.txt
gamma.txt
77gamma.txt
```

Use `select fullname` to display full filepaths instead of only filenames if you prefer.

Image here to show your file structure.
[image: psquery]

Edit to address issue in the comments:

`Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match "[a-zA-Z].nupkg"} | foreach-object {write-host $_.FullName}`

This will write out the filepaths without the additional characters of the array.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but, the above code is not displaying the filenames. I have multiple dots in the filenames as I have in my question.

Comment: @sun please see added image. The filenames do not matter. All it is looking for is 4 characters in a row. A letter, a-z or A-Z capital plus .txt

Comment: the last statement, where it says `select name`, change that to `select fullname` to display entire filepath.

Comment: Thanks, very much. Its working now. But the following statement:  Write-Host (Get-ChildItem C:\temp -recurse | Where-Object {$_.name -match "[a-zA-Z].txt"} | Select-Object Fullname)     is giving O/P like this:  @{FullName=C:\temp\test.1.beta.txt} @{FullName=C:\temp\New folder\obmessages.1.0.0.beta.txt} @{FullName=C:\temp\Nuget\.common.1.0.0beta.txt} @{FullName=C:\temp\swsetup\bos.1.0.0.beta.txt} . Can I get list of files w/o @ and {} symbols?

Comment: Yeah, you need to put the write-host part in a loop that iterates through the collection that get-childitem returns. You just have it in the wrong place. I will edit answer in a sec to show an example.

Comment: @sun Check bottom of the answer for an additional query to run

Comment: Hi @Narzard, Thanks for the reply. How can we check whether a file of above pattern exists in a given folder? Becuase I want to throw exception if any of file(s of this pattern) exist in the given folder. If does not exist, i will continue.